# Refresh page after close lightbox in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, refresh, lightbox, shortcode

is it a way to refresh page (page before open lightbox) after close a lightbox? I'm using below simple shortcode generated in WP.

```
[su_lightbox type="iframe" src="https://mypage.com" mobile="yes" class=""']Click here to open lightbox[/su_lightbox]
```

I know about answers about this, but there are from 10 years ago, maybe there was some changes from this time?

Comment: the point of a lightbox is usually not to reload the page, please can you clarify if by reload the page you are talking about the page that contains the lightbox, or the page that is opened in the lightbox ?

Comment: My goal is to reload page that contains the lightbox, right after close the lightbox.

Comment: you may be able to achieve this with JavaScript by binding a function to the event that opens the lightbox. to reload a iframe you can use `document.getElementById('the_id_of_the_iframe').contentWindow.location.reload();`